# Very cool 3D graphics on website, but what is the technology behind this?

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, 3d, html5-canvas

I discovered a very cool 3D graphics on a danish website recently. You can rotate and zoom a 3D object of the earth. I'm interested in 3D graphics on websites and I'm curious how this has been done. I'm sure it's not Flash, because I right cliked on it, and there was no info about Flash as it use to be when you right cklick on Flash graphics, so what could it be?

Link: [Link to danish website BIG](http://www.big.dk/#projects)  And then select `Locations`

Comment: It may be lazy loading plugin..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rotating globe you are referring to is actually WebGL rendered on an HTML Canvas element, and controlled via Javascript.

WebGL is powerful, but not that easy to pickup for someone without a pretty solid understanding of OpenGL-ES programming.
I would suggest using a library, the best one out there is (in my opinion) http://threejs.org, which simplifies the task by managing low-level 3D operations for you, allowing you to concentrate on high-level concepts (polygons, shading, etc). There's plenty of tutorials and examples of the typical "hello world" (which, luckily, is the representation of Earth with some interactivity on it).

Going deeper in the example you gave, I suggest you looking at this tutorial which fits well, and explains how to accomplish the same thing: http://www.smartjava.org/content/render-open-data-3d-world-globe-threejs.

Sidenote: Three.js allows rendering on WebGL, Canvas, SVG or CSS3 surfaces. WebGL is not supported on IE, but Canvas is (IE9+). This means the same (or pretty much the same) results (but with quite different performance) can be achieved on all the most common browsers.

Comment: OK, but IE9 and IE 10 don't support WebGL!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: There's a plugin for IE, adding WebGL support – http://iewebgl.com/ . So either Flash or that, with IE you've got always a plugin inbetween.

Answer (score 1):

this is done through HTML canvas tag and Javascript.
a good tutorial is [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/).

Answer (score 0):

A Combination of Html5, Jquery ,Web Fonts and Few other 3rd party javascripts have been used... to learn more you may make use of chrome web inspector to check how it was done
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/
Alternatively you may use Firebug- Firefox Addon to do the same

I am not sure whether WebGL have been used here, as i am not aware of that

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out verge3d, it simplifies the integration of 3D elements (made in blender or Maya) and export them as gltf web apps which are programmable using what they term a puzzle language, which is really just drag and drop script blocks and logic connectors. Google Studio Earth can also be implemented. But the ease of use if you don't want to do a lot of programming would be verge3d. 
 Having had a look at that site, if I was a gambling man (and I am) I'd put money on that specific implementation being done up in verge3d. From the loading screen to how the movement of the globe interacts it just feels like verge3d. (couldn't say 100% but I'd definitely put some money on it.) That and it has a WordPress plugin for easy integration and the site uses WordPress. The elements used in the website all fall within the platform so check it out. 
  [Verge3d WordPress integration](https://www.soft8soft.com/docs/manual/en/introduction/Wordpress-Plugin.html)